# PNPM WARN deprecated stringify-package

Tags: node.js, npm, pnpm

I'm using Nodejs and PNPM.

It's my first use of PNPM and I got this WARN message below.

How to solve it please ?

```
WARN  deprecated stringify-package@1.0.1: This module is not used anymore, and has been replaced by @npmcli/package-json
```

Comment: You dont. The package maintainer has marked it deprecated https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-deprecate.  Try another dependency that doesn't depend on deprecated ones, or just acknowledge the warning and understand any risks.

Comment: Also, you would get the same warning with both npm or Yarn. If you think you can ignore this warning, you may use this setting: https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmalloweddeprecatedversions